# InvalidPluginExecutionException dialog does not show up - CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Plugin on the Creation of the Quote entity from project in the CRM 2013. I want to throw exception on the success of some operations, means want to display dialog. It is working fine but it gives "ISV code aborted the operation" message at the bottom instead of Business Process error popup with actual message.

```
Message : Create
Primary Entity : quote
Action: Pre-Operation
Execution Mode: Synchronous
```

Answer (score 0):

Thi question was answered at https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/143724.aspx .